# Show that aP+bQ is also a probability measure.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So I am stuck on trying to prove that something is a probability measure.

The question is:

Show that if P and Q are two probability measures defined on the same (countable) sample space, then *aP + bQ* is also a probability measure for any two nonnegative numbers *a* and *b* satisfying *a + b = 1*

I can show that *aP + bQ* is greater than equal to 0, from the given information.

However I am not entirely sure how to prove the two other axioms to show that *aP + bQ* is a probability measure.

Comment: What have you tried towards the other two axioms? $P, Q$ are themselves probability measures, so there is nothing too complicated going on here.

Comment: I understand everything logically, just having a hard time showing it mathematically. Managed to figure out the third axiom, not sure about the 2nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two postulates to prove. Given a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ that $P, Q$ are probability measures for, it must hold:

$$
\forall A \in \mathcal{F}: \alpha P(A) + \beta Q(A) \in [0,1], \; \alpha P(\Omega) + \beta Q(\Omega) = 1.
$$

and, additionally, for every countable collection $\mathcal{A}$ of pairwise disjoint sets $A_i$, it must hold that

$$
\alpha P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) + \beta Q\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) =
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha P(A_i) + \beta Q(A_i). 
$$

The first of the above is trivial to prove since $\alpha + \beta = 1$ and $P(\cdot), Q(\cdot) \in [0, 1]$. For the second one, you already know that $P, Q$ are probability measures, so they satisfy

$$
P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(A_i), \\
Q\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Q(A_i)
$$

and therefore their sum should satisfy $\alpha P(\dots) + \beta Q(\dots) = \sum_i \alpha P(A_i) + \beta Q(A_i)$.